# removing Blure text in pickerview ios swift

Tags: ios, swift3, pickerview

i have used multiple picker view , 
but it will displayed text blur which will be in following image.
how can i remove blur effect from picker view.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFYLE.png)

Comment: How did you assign data ? Show some code please

Comment: i have assigned data like this   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        
        let lblValue: UILabel! = UILabel()
        
        lblValue?.textAlignment = .center
        lblValue?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(14.0))

        lblValue?.text = arrPickerDataSource[row]
        return lblValue!
        
    }